# Como eu faço um ctrl+C algo dentro de um form com um botão usando javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um form e um botão ao lado. Necessito copiar as informações deste form somente clicando no botão usando javascript.
O form, botão e a tentativa de função de CRTL+C é esta:

HTML

```
<label for="disable_date">URL</label>
<div class="input-group-append">
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control dropdown-toggle"
                id="input_url"
              />
              <span onclick="copyText(this)" >
              <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="button">
                <i class="dripicons-copy"></i>
              </button>
            </span>
          </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
copyText(element) {
          var txt = '';
            if (window.getSelection)
            txt = window.getSelection(); 
            else if (document.getSelection)
            txt = document.getSelection();
            else return;
            document.getElementById("a").value=txt;
            allCopied =document.getElementById("a").createTextRange();
            allCopied.execCommand("RemoveFormat");
            allCopied.execCommand("Copy");
          },
```

Answer (score 2):

Para melhor digestão da lógica e funções estude nos sites cada função, assim você poderá entender melhor...

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org)

[W#Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/default.asp)

```js
// FUNCAO COPIAR
function copiar () {

const

// CRIA VARIAVEL COM REFERENCIA DO ELEMENTO INPUT
ele = document.querySelector ('input'),

// CRIA VARIAVEL COM REFERENCIA DO ELEMENTO INPUT (OPC 2)
ele_id = document.getElementById ('ele-input');

// SELECIONA VALOR DO ELEMENTO
ele.select();

//ele_id.select();

// FUNCAO execCommand COPIA O VALOR DO ALVO
document.execCommand ('copy');

};

const

// CRIA VARIAVEL COM REFERENCIA DO ELEMENTO BOTAO QUE SERA RESPONSAVEL POR ACIONAR O EVENTO DE INTERACAO COM USUARIO E EXECUTAR A FUNCAO DE COPIAR
btn_copiar = document.getElementById ('btn-copiar');

// FUNCAO addEventListener ADICIONA EVENTO DO TIPO CLIQUE AO ELEMENTO BOTAO COM LIGACAO A FUNCAO COPIAR CASO SEJA CLICADO
btn_copiar.addEventListener ('click', copiar);
```

```html
<input id="ele-input" type="text" value="COPIAR TEXTO" required>

<button id="btn-copiar"> COPIAR </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function copyText() {
  /* Encontra o texto a ser armazenado */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("input_url");

  /* Seleciona o texto do input */
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*Solução para dispositivos móveis*/

  /* Copia o texto */
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```html
<!-- O campo a ser copiado -->
<input 
  type="text" 
  class="form-control dropdown-toggle" 
  id="input_url" 
/>

<!-- Botão -->
<span onclick="copyText()" >
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="button">
    <i class="dripicons-copy">Copiar</i>
  </button>
</span>
```

[Fonte](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp)

Comment: Olá Vitor, eu não ia comentar, mas devo dizer, é por isso que não gosto do w3schools `copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);`, é tanta coisa non-sense, parece que quem cria os exemplos mal sabe programar nas linguagens do qual eles "documentam", parece que se depararam com um erro qualquer e meteram um 999999 pra forçar resolver.

Comment: é estranho mesmo, mas parece uma solução só para exceções. Os navegadores mais modernos não precisam disso.
Acredito porém que completa a resposta, então mantive

Comment: Vou testar, tento algumas VMs e emuladores para casos assim, depois retorno, de qualquer forma foi raro as vezes que vi algo de bom sair do w3schools, infelizmente apesar de muita gente usar ele não é uma boa fonte, são códigos que funcionam, mas na pratica não ensina o que cada método/função faz exatamente e talvez por isso apareça essas situações como esse 99999 deles

Comment: Beleza, e muito obrigado pelo feedback!